# Trouble privately reading/writing data to google cloud storage

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a private bucket on Google Cloud storage and I am having trouble figuring out how to read/write data to it.

Right now I am using Amazon S3 and they make it VERY easy to do.

**Literally:**

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$config = array('key' => 'KEY','secret' => 'SECERT);
$client = S3Client::factory($config);

// Get an object.
$result = $client->getObject(array(
    'Bucket' => "the bucket",
    'Key'    => "filename.ext"
));
```

But with Google Cloud Storage, I am very confused. I've come to the conclusion that I need a signed URL but I really don't want to have to use `gsutil` everytime I want to grab data (which is a lot).

All of this is happening server-side so I can't have the customer do the whole browser pop up and sign into google sort of thing.

Is there not a way to just use an API/Secret combination like Amazon S3?

Could anyone help me figure out the easiest way to get this to work for my PHP server side application?

Answer (score 1):

From App Engine, you can use the [Google Cloud Storage PHP stream wrapper](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/) to write to GCS.

If you want your PHP script to work outside of App Engine, there is also the [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client). There is a [GCS PHP example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-php-samples) you might want to take a look at. Specifically, in your case, you'd probably want to use [Service Account Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts), for which there is [an example of here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/service-account.php).

Comment: Thanks for the help jterrace. The Service Account Authentication example seems to be close to what I need but I don't know what to include or what to do to get the Cloud Storage to work. Unfortunately I'm not using the App Engine but I'll use it if it makes it easier..